# How I can add a badge on my Dock icon using Cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, badge

I can't add a badge to my cocoa App icon on macOs BigSur.
I'm trying to update icon's badge in Dock with this code:

```
NSApp.dockTile.showsApplicationBadge = true    
NSApp.dockTile.badgeLabel = "12"
NSApp.dockTile.display()
```

But nothing happens. And I received a message in Xcode console:

```
setShowsApplicationBadge: is not yet implemented for the NSApp dockTile
```

Anybody can help with this?

Comment: Try using only `NSApp.dockTile.badgeLabel = "12"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help ((
The message in the console disappeared, but the badge still does not appear ..

Comment: What would you find if you search for "setShowsApplicationBadge: is not yet implemented for the NSApp dockTile"

Comment: From where and when do you call your code?

Comment: @Willeke, this code executed in some method of AppDelegate. I get some kind of notification, switch to the main thread and execute this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was resolved by this piece of code in AppDelegate

```
if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge]) { success, error in
                if success {
                    print("success")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
```

After this application was added to macOS settings -> Notifications and badge appeared in the Dock.
Strange situation, because on new fresh project it's just works with

```
NSApp.dockTile.badgeLabel = "12"
```

Maybe it will help somebody else.